# Why CvScalar is used

Tags: c++, opencv

I need help in understanding what is exactly is the function of CvScalar for example in the following code what is the task of scalar ?

```
 for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
{
    Point center=Point( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
    circle( image, center,faces[i].width/2,Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );
}
```

Comment: You are asking for `cvScalar`, but in your snippet you're using a `Scalar_`. The first is old syntax, the latter is new C++ syntax. Their meaning is the same, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cvScalar` is simply a convenient container for 1, 2, 3 or 4 floating point values.
The meaning of the data in such tuples is left to the user of the `cvScalar`.
For example they can be used to hold, say, Points in the plane (2-tuple), Rectangles (4-tuple), RGB colors (3-tuple), Points in a 3-D world (3-tuple) etc. The `cvScalar` is systematically implemented as a 4-tuple, with the unused values set to 0. And you are assigning 3 values in `cvScalar()` , it will result in the color made by combining these 3 values `Blue = 255, Green = 0, Red = 255`
You will get definition of `cvScalar` inside `types_c.h`

Comment: Thanks for the answers                                                                          What is the difference in I passed the values as (255,0,255) ?

Comment: The difference is the color of your circle. If you enter (0,0,0) then circle color will be BLACK , if (255,255,255) then circle color will be WHITE and (255,0,255) then circle color will be PINK.

Comment: I mean passing the numbers without using scalar

Comment: There will be an error 'could not convert '(0, 255)' from 'int' to 'CvScalar''