# use cvSet2D in gray scale image in C language?

Tags: c, opencv

I want to set pixel value in given bmp image using CvSet2D but I want to access only the first value. Could you explain what the 4 arguments of CvSet2D are for?

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("initial.bmp",1);

    int f = 123;
    cvSet2D(img, 1, 2, f); // here is the error
    //cvSet2D(img, 1, 2, cvScalar(f)); // error also this way

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error that says:

```
incompatible type for argument 4 of 'cvSet2D'
```

I just need to set pixel value of a gray scale image, how con I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612552/purpose-of-cvget2d-and-cvset2d) question.

> C: void cvSet2D(CvArr* arr, int idx0, int idx1, CvScalar value)

The arguments are:

- **arr** -  Input array (i.e. the image)
- **idx0** – The first zero-based component of the element index (i.e. row)
- **idx1** – The second zero-based component of the element index (i.e column)
- **value** – The assigned value

To know what `cvScalar` is, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583694/why-cvscalar-is-used/31583848#31583848) and

> The `cvScalar` is simply a convenient container for 1, 2, 3 or 4 floating point values.

You should do something like:

```
uchar f = 123;
CvScalar scalar = cvGet2D(img, 1, 2);
scalar.val[0] = f;
cvSet2D(img, 1, 2, scalar);
```

Comment: this cvSet2D(img, 1, 2, cvScalar(f)); doesn't work at all

Comment: @RiwaMl it should work, what's the error? Also post a small sample where you also show how you create the image.

Comment: @RiwaMl updated the snippet about `cvSet2D`. It works as expected. Is it different from what you're doing? Post your code...

Comment: the error is
too few arguments to function 'cvScalar'

Comment: it is C programming not C++

Comment: Yeah, I was using C++ wrapper to C stuff. Check updated snippet

Comment: @RiwaMl from your posted code (which you should add to your question) I think I finally got what you meant. Check if it's ok now. Please note that a clear question with all needed info will get you the correct answer sooner!

Comment: @RiwaMl I added the relevant code to the question, now you can delete your answer. If you find this answer useful, please accept it and/or upvote. Or comment to get additional information. To use C++ functions, you should `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`